# c++ libraries for dealing with distributed matrices on a grid

Tags: c++, distributed-computing

Which c++ libraries (or libraries in Fortran with c++ interfaces) do you recommend for doing BLAS or Sparse BLAS operations on distributed matrices in terms of speed and ease of use?

Comment: I thought MPI was standard for tasks like this?

Comment: @Nobody: PBLAS is the standard for distributed basic linear algebra (you have SCALAPACK for the "less basic" algorithms, built on top of PBLAS). MPI is at the base of PBLAS, through the BLACS subroutines.

Answer (score 3):

Use [PBLAS](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/pblas_qref.html) directly. I don't happen to know of any C++ library to ease this. There is http://cppscalapack.sourceforge.net/, but it seems not maintained any more (last update in 2004) and in an alpha stage.

Distributed linear algebra is quite cumbersome to do, and this will involve a lot of work whatever library you happen to use. I therefore think that using PBLAS directly, abstracting the computations in classes as you go is a quite sensible thing to do: understanding the Fortran interface is not the hard part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. If I use PBLAS from MKL, I can't find BLACS interface in c++ in MKL. Can I use MPI instead of BLACS in this case?

Comment: BLACS can be found at netlib, and serves as a layer between PBLAS and MPI.

Comment: What do you think of Trilinos and Petsc ?

Comment: And what about sparse BLAS opeartions?